# SQL, return comma separated list of each value from SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, express

I am making an express web app and as part of it I am querying an SQL database that has a table of users (`dbo.tbl_user` with data such as name, role, email etc.

I want to query the DB so that a list of names are returned in comma separated values. When I use `'SELECT name FROM dbo.tbl_user'` I get:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Tom"
    },
    {
        "name": "Dick"
    },
    {
        "name": "Harry"
    }
]
```

however I want

```
[
    "Tom","Dick","Harry"
]
```

Searching online I can only find ways of getting back `[{"Tom,Dick,Harry"}]` which is **not** what I want as the values are not separated out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: see if “https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/how-to-concatenate-text-from-multiple-rows-into-a-single-text-string-in-sql-serv” answers your question.

Comment: Hi, I dont want a single text string, instead multiple comma separated text strings

Comment: That's a JSON array. I suggest searching on that term

Comment: When you use `SELECT name FROM dbo.tbl_user`, you are simply asking for a resultset that has one column per row, which is the `name` column. That is why you get three separate records--it's what you asked for. You need to look at ways of concatenating these row results into a single result value that suits your JSON requirement.

Comment: The original query returns the _JSON representation of the result set_, per that query method used (it would be different if using a local SqlConnection in code, which uses a ResultSet instead..). This is likely a fixed format/structure, independent of data. Perform a transformation in the consumer to convert (after JSON deserialization) the array-of-objects to array-of-name-strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you simply use JS to get what you want from what you got from the query?

```
const sqlResult = [
    {
        "name": "Tom"
    },
    {
        "name": "Dick"
    },
    {
        "name": "Harry"
    }
];

const onlyNamesArr = sqlResult.map(i => i.name);   // returns ["Tom", "Dick", "Harry"]
```